# Manual mock with Jest in Nestjs not working

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, nestjs

Having this mock service:

```js
// /catalogue/__mock__/catalogue.service.ts
export const CatalogueService = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    filterRulesFor: jest.fn().mockImplementation((role: Roles): Rule[] => rules.filter(r => r.roles.includes(role))
    fetchCountries: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of(countriesStub())),
  }
});
```

In the next scaffolding:

```
/catalogue
  /__mock__
    catalogue.service.ts
  /tests
    catalogue.controller.spec.ts
  catalogue.module.ts
  catalogue.controller.ts
  catalogue.service.ts
```

I want to use the mock service inside the `catalogue.controller.spec.ts`:

```js
// /catalogue/tests/catalogue.controller.spec.ts
import { CatalogueController } from '../catalogue.controller';
import { CatalogueService } from '../catalogue.service';

jest.mock('../catalogue.service'); // <----- manual mocking here

describe('CatalogueController', () => {
  let controller: CatalogueController;
  let service: CatalogueService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [UtilsModule],
      controllers: [CatalogueController],
      providers: [CatalogueService],
    })
    .compile();

    controller = module.get<CatalogueController>(CatalogueController);
    service = module.get<CatalogueService>(CatalogueService);
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
}
```

But when I try to use it:

```js
describe('getCountries', () => {
  let countries: Country[];
  beforeEach(async () => {
    service.fetchCountries()
    .subscribe(countries => console.log(countries)); // <----- here

    countries = await firstValueFrom(controller.getCountries());
  });

  it('should be called', () => {
    expect(service.fetchCountries).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('should not be empty', () => {
    expect(countries.length).toBe(countriesStub().length);
  });
});
```

It gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` as if the mock service does not have the functions defined.

[image: error]

If I write the mock right in the same file it just works but that's not what I want:

```js
let controller: CatalogueController;
let service: CatalogueService;

// vvvvv Mock service here vvvv
const mockCatalogueService = {
  filterRulesFor: jest.fn().mockImplementation((role: Roles): Rule[] => rules.filter(r => r.roles.includes(role))),
  fetchCountries: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of(countriesStub())),
};

beforeEach(async () => {
  const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [UtilsModule],
    controllers: [CatalogueController],
    providers: [CatalogueService],
  })
  .overrideProvider(CatalogueService) // <--- Implementing here
  .useValue(mockCatalogueService)     // <--- and here
  .compile();

  controller = module.get<CatalogueController>(CatalogueController);
  service = module.get<CatalogueService>(CatalogueService);
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Manual mock in jest only mock via `import` statement. But Nestjs implement DJ, this mean some objects such as service, controller,... get from container that contain all instance object of application. You can try this way

```
import { CatalogueService } from '../catalogue.service';

jest.mock('../catalogue.service');
//...
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [UtilsModule],
  controllers: [CatalogueController],
  providers: [CatalogueService],
})
.useMocker((token) => {
  switch (token) {
    case CatalogueService:
      return CatalogueService;
    // more mock object at here
  }
})
.compile();
```